# reshape2 dcast non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, reshape2, dcast

I am trying to convert a data frame from long to wide using `dcast` from `reshape2`.

I create a data frame like this:

```
> Person=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C")
> Object=c("car", "watch", "bike", "phone","car","skateboard","car","bike","motorcycle")
> Value=c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1")
> df=data.frame(Person, Object, Value)
```

and get,

```
> df
   Person     Object Value
1       A        car     1
2       A      watch     1
3       A       bike     1
4       A      phone     1
5       B        car     1
6       B skateboard     1
7       C        car     1
8       C       bike     1
9       C motorcycle     1
10      C         TV     1
```

Then, with dcast

```
> library(reshape2)
> dcast(df, Person + Object, variable.var="Value", fun.aggregate=length)
Error in Person + Object : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Why dcast would need numeric argument for Person and Object column anyway?

I am trying to get this output:

```
Person    car    watch    bike    phone    skateboard    motorcycle    TV
     A      1        1       1        1             0             0     0
     B      1        0       0        0             1             0     0
     C      1        0       1        0             0             1     1
```

*** EDIT ***
@neilfws found a solution:

```
dcast(df, Person ~ . + Object, variable.var="Value")
```

However, when the data frame is imported from a tab-delimited file:

```
df = read.table("Person_Object.tab", header=T, sep="\t")
```

the same dcast command returns:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Person' not found
```

Comment: You need to specify a formula, containing a `~`, otherwise R thinks you're trying to add two numbers. Perhaps `Person + Object ~ .` ?

Comment: @neilfws: Thanks ! `dcast(df, Person ~ . + Object, variable.var="Value")` kind of works.

Comment: But importing the same data frame from a file returns a different error (see edit above)

Comment: Must be some issue with the file or with syntax. Does `colnames(df)` show a column named `Person` ?

Comment: Yes, `colnames(df)` returns `[1] "Person"   "Object" "Value" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing how to fill empty cells.

```
Person=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C")
Object=c("car", "watch", "bike", "phone","car","skateboard","car","bike","motorcycle", "TV")
Value=c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1")

# note the extra parameter StringsAsFactors - needed so that "0" can be used 
df=data.frame(Person, Object, Value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(reshape2)
dcast(df, Person ~ Object, value.var="Value", fill = "0")

#   Person bike car motorcycle phone skateboard TV watch
# 1      A    1   1          0     1          0  0     1
# 2      B    0   1          0     0          1  0     0
# 3      C    1   1          1     0          0  1     0
>
```

Comment: Great ! `stringsAsfactors=FALSE` even solved the issue with importing the file (see edit). Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    spread(Object, Value, fill = 0)
#   Person bike car motorcycle phone skateboard TV watch
#1      A    1   1          0     1          0  0     1
#2      B    0   1          0     0          1  0     0
#3      C    1   1          1     0          0  1     0
```